# How to spin up multiple aws instances and assign given range of IP addresses using ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, ansible

The objective is to spin up multiple instances which can be achieved using `count` but I have been give specific range of private IP addresses, and want to assign them to the instances.

Below is my present playbook,

```
---
  - name: Provision an EC2 Instance
    hosts: local
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    tags: provisioning
    # Necessary Variables for creating/provisioning the EC2 Instance
    vars:
      instance_type: t2.micro
      security_group: default # Change the security group name here
      image: ami-a9d276c9 # Change the AMI, from which you want to launch the server
      region: us-west-2 # Change the Region
      keypair: ansible # Change the keypair name
      ip_addresses:
        - 172.31.1.117/32
        - 172.31.1.118/32
      count: 2

    tasks:

      - name: Launch the new EC2 Instance
        local_action: ec2
                      group={{ security_group }}
                      instance_type={{ instance_type}}
                      image={{ image }}
                      wait=true
                      region={{ region }}
                      keypair={{ keypair }}
                      count={{count}}
                      vpc_subnet_id=subnet-xxxxxxx
#                      private_ip={{private_ip}}
        with_items: ip_addresses
        register: ec2

      - name: Wait for SSH to come up
        local_action: wait_for
                      host={{ item.public_ip }}
                      port=22
                      state=started
        with_items: ec2.instances

      - name: Add tag to Instance(s)
        local_action: ec2_tag resource={{ item.id }} region={{ region }} state=present
        with_items: ec2.instances
        args:
          tags:
            Name: ansible

      - name: Update system
        apt: update_cache=yes

      - name: Install Git
        apt:
          name: git
          state: present

      - name: Install Python2.7
        apt:
          name: python=2.7
          state: present

      - name: Install Java
        apt:
          name: openjdk-8-jdk
          state: present
```

Which is although bringing up the instances but not assigning the IP addresses intended to be assigned. and I'm getting following warning

```
PLAY [Provision an EC2 Instance] ***********************************************

TASK [Launch the new EC2 Instance] *********************************************
changed: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=172.31.1.117/32)
changed: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=172.31.1.118/32)
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined attribute, in the future this will be a fatal error.. This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be 
disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
```

Please suggest me the best possible way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are giving `count=2`, so 2 instances will be launched
- Your IP addresses are wrong, you are giving a CIDR instead of IP
- You are not using the IP address anywhere in your code when launching the instances

How to fix?

```
  ip_addresses:
    - 172.31.1.117
    - 172.31.1.118
```

- Don't specify `count` in `ec2` module
- Loop through the list of ipaddresses (there are 2 of them)
- Make sure you use the IP by referencing `{item}`

Like this:

```
private_ip={{item}}
```